# How to make Player rotation driven by mixture of camera rotation *and* keyboard rotation?

Tags: unity

Currently I have these lines of code driving Player rotation:

```
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0.0f, verticalInput).normalized;

    if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero)
    {
        Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(moveDirection);
        targetRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotDegPerSecond * Time.deltaTime);           
        rigidBody.MoveRotation(targetRotation);
    }
```

This works well to rotate the Player with the keyboard input.

However, I would like my Camera to be able to influence player rotation as well.

How can I add code to make Player rotation determined from both Keyboard Input *and* Camera rotation together?

Comment: How would you like the camera to influence the player rotation? Describe your desired behaviour in detail, then we can help you achieve that target.

Comment: So, this is a third person game with the camera following behind Player. Currently the camera is able to freely look 360 around the player, without affecting player movement. I would want to get it so that if user rotates the camera, then the Player rotates to face where the camera is facing.

Comment: It sounds like you want to implement "camera-relative 3rd person movement". [We have lots of existing Q&A about that available to consult](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bunity%5D+camera-relative).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this through a YouTube tutorial that implements Cinemachine. The core important lines are:

```
horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");


moveDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0.0f, verticalInput).normalized;
moveDirection = (Quaternion.AngleAxis(cameraTransform.rotation.eulerAngles.y, Vector3.up) * moveDirection).normalized;
```

where `cameraTransform` is declared at the top (`public Transform cameraTransform;`) and is a reference to your camera. In this case, it is my Cinemachine camera, implemented with the settings shown here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jiyOZbKRfaY

Good luck all!